# Theme Choosing Option for a Django Project not working properly

Tags: python, django

Helloo,

I am following a tutorial to allow User to select Light/Dark Mode using HTML, CSS, JS.

I have following documentation and tutorial but the issue is that the content of the page itself is not showing and I am not sure the reason.

So what I did is I created 2 css files dark and light, and create a `mode` application with the settings.

I am currently receiving an error:

```
django.contrib.auth.models.User.setting.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no setting.
```

To start here is the base.html

```
    <link id="mystylesheet" href="{% static 'css/app-light.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Mode -->
        <div id="mode" class="section" style="padding-top: 1rem; padding-bottom: 3rem;text-align: right">
            <button onclick="swapStyle('css/app-light.css')" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Light Mode</button>
            <button onclick="swapStyle('css/app-dark.css')" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Dark Mode</button>
        </div>
        <!-- Mode -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');



        var cssFile = "{% static 'css' %}"


        function swapStyles(sheet){
            document.getElementById('mystylesheet').href = cssFile + '/' + sheet
            localStorage.setItem('theme', sheet)

            updateTheme(sheet)
        }


        function loadSettings(){
            //Call data and set local storage

            var url = "{% url 'mode:user_settings' %}"
            fetch(url, {
                method:'GET',
                headers:{
                    'Content-type':'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then(function(data){

                console.log('Data:', data)

                var theme = data.value;

                if (theme == 'light.css' || null){
                    swapStyles('light.css')
                }else if(theme == 'dark.css'){
                    swapStyles('dark.css')
                }


            })

        }

        loadSettings()


        function updateTheme(theme){
            var url = "{% url 'mode:update_theme' %}"
            fetch(url, {
                method:'POST',
                headers:{
                    'Content-type':'application/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
                },
                body:JSON.stringify({'theme':theme})
            })
        }
    </script>
```

Here is the model.py

```
class Setting(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

here is the views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html')


def userSettings(request):
    user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(id=1)
    setting = user.setting

    seralizer = UserSerailizer(setting, many=False)

    return JsonResponse(seralizer.data, safe=False)


def updateTheme(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    theme = data['theme']

    user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(id=1)
    user.setting.value = theme
    user.setting.save()
    print('Request:', theme)
    return JsonResponse('Updated..', safe=False)
```

Here is the serializer.py

```
from .models import *

class UserSerailizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Setting
        fields = '__all__'
```

Here is urls.py

```
app_name = 'mode'


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),

    path('user_settings/', views.userSettings, name="user_settings"),

    path('update_theme/', views.updateTheme, name="update_theme"),

]
```

Here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project\mode\views.py", line 17, in userSettings
    setting = user.setting
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 421, in __get__
    raise self.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist(
django.contrib.auth.models.User.setting.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no setting.
```

Comment: Did you read traceback? your user does not have related Settings in database

Comment: I know but shouldnt it pick it up from Json updated theme.

Comment: Have to tried moving the updateTheme function before userSettings? could be trying to assign user settings before it is saved

Comment: @ClarkeFL yes in the admin it is requiring me to assign a user, should it choose automatically the logged in User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the case when a `user` will not have a `setting` in `userSettings` function.

```
def userSettings(request):
    user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(id=1)
    setting = getattr(user, 'setting', None)

    if setting:
        seralizer = UserSerailizer(setting, many=False)
        return JsonResponse(seralizer.data, safe=False)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'message': "User don't have a setting."}, safe=False)
```

And also make sure that `updateTheme` function works perfectly. If it doesn't work try following.

```
def updateTheme(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    theme = data['theme']

    user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(id=1)
    setting = Setting.objects.get_or_create(user=user, value=theme, name='a name')
    setting.save()
    print('Request:', theme)
    return JsonResponse('Updated..', safe=False)
```

Note that in the `name` field of `Setting` model you didn't pass `null=True`. So you have to pass `name` when creating a setting of a user.

Also in your base.html you are using `onclick="swapStyle()"` yet your javascript function is `function swapStyles(){}`. Change this

Comment: I have followed your guide but nothing is showing yet, no errors but in the console `Data: 
{message: "User don't have a setting."}
message: "User don't have a setting."
__proto__: Object`

Comment: also in the name `name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)`

Comment: Have you update `updateTheme` function as well?

Comment: yes,  also when I click the buttons for the light or dark mode I receive this error in the console `Uncaught ReferenceError: swapStyle is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):202)`

Comment: @A_K change swapStyle to swapStyles or change the function to swapStyle in base.html

Answer (score 1):

```
setting = getattr(user, 'setting', None)
```